# Render canvas full screen on a monitor with a particular resolution

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a monitor of size 800 x 480. I would like to render an HTML5 Canvas that fills the entire monitor in a full screen browser setting (no toolbar, dock, taskbar, browser window, etc) such that one pixel in canvas coordinate space corresponds exactly to one pixel in monitor coordinate space.

For example, I would like to ensure that canvas(0,0) corresponds physically to the top left pixel on the monitor.

Just making the canvas fill the width and height of the webpage doesn't make sense because the viewport isn't the same size as the entire monitor.

Would appreciate some advice on how to go about solving this.

Thanks!

Comment: why you need pixel level match?

Comment: the position of (0,0) would probably not change anyway.

Comment: @appleapple it's for a science experiment. I used the (0, 0) example because an incorrect implementation would map (0, 0) in canvas coordinate space to say a pixel on the toolbar or address bar. I want these to disappear.

Comment: can you share your incorrect implementation?

Comment: Sure. `<canvas width="800px" height="480px">`. This creates a small box within the browser window and doesn't fill the entire screen. In this case, (0, 0) in canvas space would map to the top left corner of the toolbar on macOS since the canvas has not filled the entire screen.

Comment: have you tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API ? if it's a mac only issue then you should apply the tag.

Comment: No I didn't specify this is a Mac only issue, more just ignorance on my part - but thanks I will look into the Fullscreen API equivalent for Google Chrome.

Comment: and I really don't understand, (0, 0) *in canvas space* is no doubt *inside* canvas, I don't get why it can be toolbar.

Comment: @appleapple It can be in the toolbar in Monitor coordinate space.

Comment: sorry not being clear, I mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullscreen which is well supported.